# Repeat Customers with multiple purchases on the same day counts a 1

Tags: sql-server, repeat

I am trying to wrap my head around this problem.  I was asked to create a report that show repeat customers in our database.

One of the requirements is if a customer has more than 1 order on a specific date, it would only count as 1. 
Then if they have more than 1 purchase date, they would then count as a repeat customer.

Searching on here, I found this which works for finding the Customers with more then 1 purchase on a specific purchase date.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.[CustomerName], s.PurchaseDate

FROM Reports.vw_Repeat s WHERE s.PurchaseDate <> ''    

GROUP BY s.[CustomerName] , cast(s.PurchaseDate as date)

HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This MSSQL code works like it should, by showing customers who had more than 1 purchase on the same date.
My problem is what would the best approach be to Join this into another query (this is where i need help) that then shows a complete repeat customer list where customers with more than 1 purchase would be returned.

I am using MSSQL.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the other query you want to join?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have the query written out.  I assumed I would have to include the first query with another query  to complete what I am trying to do.  I am still new to this and didn't know the best route to take on the second query.

Comment: remove distinct, it does nothing useful in that query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thanks to everyone for the help. 
@MaxSzczurek suggested I use table-valued functions. After looking into this more, I ended up using just a temporary table first to get the DISTINCT purchase dates for each Customer.  I then loaded that into another temp table RIGHT JOINED to the main table.  This gave me the result I was looking for.  Its a little(lot) ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a parameter to a query and join the result, that's what table-valued functions are for. When you join it, you use CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY instead of an INNER JOIN or a LEFT JOIN.

Also, I think this goes without saying, but when you check if PurchaseDate is empty:

```
WHERE s.PurchaseDate <> ''
```

Could be issues there... it implies it's a varchar field instead of a datetime (yes?) and doesn't handle null values. You might, at least, want to replace that with ISNULL(s.PurchaseDate, '') <> ''. If it's actually a datetime, use IS NOT NULL instead of <> ''.

(Edited to add sample data and DDL statements. I recommend adding these to SQL posts to assist answerers. Also, I made purchasedate a varchar instead of a datetime because of the string comparison in the query.)

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx

```
CREATE TABLE company (company_name VARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO company VALUES ('Company1'), ('Company2')

CREATE TABLE vw_repeat (customername VARCHAR(25), purchasedate VARCHAR(25), company VARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO vw_repeat VALUES ('Cust1', '11/16/2017', 'Company1')
INSERT INTO vw_repeat VALUES ('Cust1', '11/16/2017', 'Company1')
INSERT INTO vw_repeat VALUES ('Cust2', '11/16/2017', 'Company2')

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].tf_customers
(
    @company varchar(25)    
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
(
    SELECT s.[CustomerName], cast(s.PurchaseDate as date) PurchaseDate
    FROM vw_Repeat s 
    WHERE s.PurchaseDate <> '' AND s.Company = @company 
    GROUP BY s.[CustomerName] , cast(s.PurchaseDate as date)
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
GO

SELECT * 
FROM company c
CROSS APPLY tf_customers(c.company_name)
```

Comment: remove distinct, it does nothing useful in that query.... what does `group by` do? (make rows unique) what does "distinct" do? (make rows unique) which is done first? (group by) .....

Comment: @MaxSzczurek recommend removal of `distinct`

Comment: @MaxSzczurek : I guess I am doing something wrong as it returns no rows.   I had a few questions if you had the time. I re-edited the initial SQL I posted and removed the Company aspect as I could do that in the final SELECT/WHERE statements and it was originally used just to shrink the returned data.  How would this then effect the SQL?  To be clear the SQL you posted was how I executed it, leaving the Company part in.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Yep! Removed the distinct - I fixed the grouping but forgot to remove it. :)

Comment: @triton_9000 Check the edit - I added sample DDL and DML statements. This returns a row with the given sample data. Maybe this can clear something up for you.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, you need to move `distinct` into your `having` clause because you want to include only customers that have more than 1 distinct purchase date.

Also, only group by the customer id because the different dates have to be part of the same group for `count distinct` to work.

```
SELECT s.[CustomerName], COUNT(distinct cast(s.PurchaseDate as date))
FROM Reports.vw_Repeat s WHERE s.PurchaseDate <> ''    
GROUP BY s.[CustomerName] 
HAVING COUNT(distinct cast(s.PurchaseDate as date)) > 1;
```

Comment: I tried this and it also returned 0 rows.  The query I have in my question above does return rows.  Your example seemed to be promising though.

Comment: can you show some sample data for `select CustomerName, cast(s.PurchaseDate as date)`? I wonder if the cast is working correctly

Comment: Here is some sample data returned.  The customer name has been concated with there zipcode in the vw_Repeat; I edited the customer names though:      xxxx - 95688 2016-01-13
xxxx - 91773 2016-02-01
xxxx - 29201 2016-02-17
xxxx - 72730 2016-03-25
xxxx - 30330 2016-03-30

Comment: The cast seems to not be needed. I removed the cast and the first query still works. But the one you suggested does not.  Although it makes sense, I dont get why it wont return anything. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: This seems to work if I remove the the DISTINCT from the COUNT in the SELECT statement.  `SELECT s.[CustomerName], COUNT(s.PurchaseDate)
FROM Reports.vw_Repeat s WHERE s.PurchaseDate <> ''    
GROUP BY s.[CustomerName] 
HAVING COUNT(distinct s.PurchaseDate) > 1;` And also removing the CAST from the PurchaseDate.  So far this seems to work...need to spot check.

Comment: Never mind above...this just gives me the count for the days where there was more than one purchase. Which makes sense now.